# Why do these objects have different constructor functions?

Tags: javascript

Im a newbie to JavaScript and trying to create objects. Case 2 works fine, but case 1 doesn't show me the output I expect.

Question: Why am I able to view the constructor in case 2 and not in case 1?

Case 1

```
function newemp() {
    return {
        'name':'bob',
        'age':20
    };
}
fred = newemp()
document.write(fred.constructor)
```

Case 2

```
function employee(name,jobtitle,born) {
    this.name=name;
    this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
    this.born=born;
}

var fred=new employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman",1970);
document.write(fred.constructor);
```

Output case 1

```
function Object() { [native code] }
```

Output case 2

```
function employee(name, jobtitle, born) { this.name=name; this.jobtitle=jobtitle;` this.born=born; }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: @user1050619 Was just wondering how your accepted answer solves the issue. Could you please enlighten me, may be i can learn something new...

Comment: @PSL: it did not solve the problem..Its more for my learning and experimental purpose...Now, i got the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help to slove case1 prob

```
var anObj = {
    a: "test",
    b: "jest"
};

var bObj = Object.create(anObj);
```

Comment: How exactly does it solve the problem? What is the problem actually?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case to are just returning an object literal from the function `newemp` and what you are seeing is the default constructor of a Javascript Object. Every object in javascript has a built in constructor. What you are seeing is what you will see when you do:

```
var ob = {};
console.log(ob.constructor);
```

In the second case you are creating an object of type `employee` by using the keyword  and the constructor points to `employee`.

Since constructors are not readonly you can set it inside your function. (But i am not sure why you would need it at all in your particular scenario)

```
function newemp() {
    var ob =  {
        'name': 'bob',
            'age': 20
    };
    ob.constructor = newemp; //Set the constructor
    return ob;
}
fred = newemp();
console.log(fred.constructor);
```

[Some reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)